# How to root Innos A35

Tags: rooting

I bought a dual sim phone from a local carrier which has been branded in their own name. After searching I found that it is the [innos A35](http://www.innos.com/en/productinfo.aspx?id=1) phone. It has dual sim support and sim1 has been locked to the carrier I have mentioned.
For sim2, the "Use only 2G networks" tick is ticked and it cannot be unticked(the tick is disabled). Due to this reason I can only access Internet through the above mentioned carrier's connection.

My first question is, will rooting the phone allow me to remove the mentioned restrictions?

My second question is about how to root the phone. Following [this guide](http://www.pocketables.com/2011/06/how-to-manually-root-almost-any-android-device.html) I got stuck at the command `$./psneuter` with the error `Failed to set prot mask (Inappropriate ioctl for device)`. The version of Android is 2.3.5

Does anyone know a solution to this problem?

Comment: I cannot directly help you, but I've added your device to our [rooting index](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/1185/16575). You might check there for other methods or similar devices (and somebody else checking there might find your post and come for help :)

Comment: @Izzy Following the steps at http://www.erodov.com/forums/how-root-any-android-device-manually/43325-page2.html worked for me to root the device. Still have to look into removing the restrictions. Should that be added as an answer? Do you know or can you suggest a way to remove the restrictions after gaining root access?

Comment: If you succeeded with those steps, you should certainly make that an answer! Please include a basic abstract (not only the link), and *additionally* put the link as source. As to the restrictions: I suggest making that a separate question, and using the `sim-unlocking` tag (as that is what it refers to). But before doing so, check at least the [most frequented questions on this topic](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sim-unlocking) -- I'm pretty sure that makes another question obsolete :)

Answer (score 1):

Steps taken from http://www.erodov.com/forums/how-root-any-android-device-manually/43325-page2.html. Many thanks to the author of that post.

To verify adb is properly installed and that your device is recognized run

```
adb devices
```

Copy busybox, su, superuser.apk to /data/local/tmp/ using adb. These files are available in the SuperOneClick zip file. Copy the needed files to the phone using the following commands

```
adb push busybox /data/local/tmp 
adb push su /data/local/tmp adb push
Superuser.apk /data/local/tmp
```

run adb shell

```
adb shell
```

set the permissions to the copied files

```
chmod 6755 /data/local/tmp/su
chmod 755 /data/local/tmp/busybox
chmod 644 /data/local/tmp/Superuser.apk
```

Turn off your Android device using the power button.

Now you need to reboot your computer into a Linux distro which has a file manager.When you have booted into Linux, open up terminal and open the file browser as root.Now put your Android device into Download mode. For Innos A35 press and hold the volume up and down keys at the same time for a while (5 seconds?) and while holding them plug in the phone to the USB port of the computer. Now, a few drives will be detected from your phone and shown in the computer. This means you're in download mode.

Navigate to the folder where you copied files to the phone and verify that you have the files you sent to the device viz. su, busybox and Superuser.apk

Move/cut-paste su and busybox to /bin/

Move/cut-paste Superuser.apk to /app/

Now pull out the battery from your Android device.

Now simply turn on your device.
You must now have root.

Verify by running:

```
adb shell
su
```

Read more: http://www.erodov.com/forums/how-root-any-android-device-manually/43325-page2.html#ixzz2S5wcT78x

Comment: if anybody could do this thus simple then there's no security of the phone at all. Anybody could just steal your private life on your device.

Answer (score 0):

If you like it the phone is rootable via vroot. I have tested it for myself and it works. Just remember to replace the super user app with an English one after rooting.

sorry I forgot the link.here it is http://vrootdownload.info/VRoot.zip if adb drivers bothers you, use pda net http://pdanet.co/a/ sorry again

one more thing,I honestly don't think that erodov.com method works.I failed to get it right on any device, but that trick of editing system files without root is great for changing the boot animation or installing sinhala fonts without busting the warranty

Comment: Could you please include a link to vroot? That would make your answer even more helpful.