# what is the download mode

Tags: boot, downloading

could anybody explain what is this download mode?

As described in here [How to root Innos A35](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/44699/how-to-root-innos-a35)
as I hold vol up +vol down 5 seconds and at the same time connecting the USB cable to
my computer it shows up a removable disk and unknown drivers in windows 7.

My phone is also Innos A35 device locally sold as i35 from dialog telecom.

What are those? And what is this `download` mode?

But unlike the recovery mode, I didn't get a screen up. Is these two modes all coming
from ROM. what kind of code is there on ROM. [Well in x86 computer I could review 
a opensource bios implementation, any idea on Android ARM ?].Where that consoles 
come from?

Where is uboot located? Is this download mode is a mode that programmed into a ROM, where
I could not change it?

I have read the boot procedure of a typical android phone. But can't organize the info
with this.

Comment: Download mode is for flashing radio firmware/rom upgrade through official means..its an open-ended question as there's no reference of your device that spurred the question on... can you include your device please?

Comment: my device is innos A35 as well.

Comment: Some devices uses U-Boot over the generic boot, its a bootloader code found in the `/boot` partition, for details of boot - see [this](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/40419/is-it-possible-to-boot-an-android-phone-from-a-usb-drive/41223#41223) As for Download mode, for example ODIN is commonly used on Samsung devices to flash ROMs, those devices needs to be in download mode prior to flashing.

Comment: @t0mm13b I'd say you should merge your two comments into an answer :)

Comment: if that is a partition under linux/android. you tell me how this happen? In wikipedia page it said that bootcode is completely isolated from the android/linux itself. Could you please explain that also to me in your answer.

Comment: And yes Izzy, I think he knows the right answer that I'm seeking. Please merge as Izzy told, so I could give some credit to the contributor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Download mode is for flashing radio firmware/ROM upgrade through official means.

Some devices uses U-Boot over the generic boot, it is a boot-loader code found in read-only ROM chip on the board, which uses a certain memory address offset, in which the kernel from the `/boot` partition gets loaded into that specific certain memory address offset and jumps into that address and the kernel starts running.

For details of the generic LK boot which is employed by most, if not all, Qualcomm based devices, see [this](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/40419/is-it-possible-to-boot-an-android-phone-from-a-usb-drive/41223#41223)

As for Download mode, for example ODIN is commonly used on Samsung devices to flash ROMs, those devices needs to be in download mode prior to flashing. However, ODIN is not the official way to do it, rather Kies, is the official route in upgrading the firmware, this is for Samsung devices for example.

Comment: I've reviewed your answer that you referenced 'this' . It seems like you are a great kernel hacker.

Answer (score 1):

The device has both "download mode" and "bulk mode" as part of the SOC. When it is turned on, it decides if it should jump to any of those modes, or actually boot the "main processor". If it does, then the preloader/secondary bootloader (two different names for the same thing) kicks in. If you turn the device on, the preloader will run the bootloader (on QC devices usually the lk that was referred on another answer).

The bulk mode is meant to expose, in bulk, the device's partitions.
The download mode is meant to be used to push a programmer into the device and run it.